# Strange sound right after loading a saved game

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

For long time now I hear strange sound right after loading any saved game - it wasn't like this from the beginning but can't remember when it started.

Can't really describe it, so I recorded it - you can [hear it here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2aC2T9c9Xs).

My best guess is that some sort of item is responsible for this but no clue what it might be. Anyone faced this and found out more?

Note: the sound is not triggering after fast travel, only after loading.

Comment: Not something I am sure of so wont post an answer, but it could be a flamed weapon being put into the characters hand or on their back or what not.

Comment: Thanks James but my equipped weapon is ordinary Dwarven Battleaxe, nothing magical and so it my follower's weapon.

Comment: sounds like a spell effect of some kind, is your follower a caster of spells by any chance?

Comment: +1 for either weapon or equipped spell, for you or your follower. Did you try leaving all of your stuff in a chest, not equipping any magic, and then doing a fast travel?

Comment: @yx. my follower is Lydia, no caster and no spells.. though when you mention it I do have enchanted gauntlets. I'll try to follow  Mikalichov advice and see what happens.

Comment: @Mikalichov thanks for the tip, will do that - but will have to save without any items then load, fast travel isn't triggering the sound. (Will add that to my post as well)

Comment: Getting naked seems to solve lots of problems.

Comment: @Mikalichov no luck.. dumped all items (my own and my followers') into a chest, saved, loaded and.. same sound exactly. :(

Comment: @Andy lol that might be true but even with no items at all I can't get naked. ;)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Well, that's weirder. Can you try without your follower, and without your horse? And check in the Magic/Shouts menu -> active effects, to see if there are some things (might be a disease, or the Standing Stone effect, or an Altar effect (hope not for the two last one, as we will have no way of knowing)

Comment: @Mikalichov thanks, tried without follower and I prefer feet over horse - no luck. Turned to be some magic spell I had as favourite or equipped yx. was correct after all - will post separate comment.

Comment: @yx. I unfavourited and unequipped all my spells and shouts, saved, loaded and.. the sound was gone! Couldn't figure which was the culprit (have over 20) but your direction was correct please post as answer so I can close this case properly. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard feel free to write up exactly what you did as an answer to your problem, I have no issues with you posting it.

Comment: And now, I cannot not hear the sound I have when I load/travel :p

Comment: @yx. done, followed your request. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @Mikalichov sorry not sure what you meant in your last comment? Anyway, you also gave useful tips to thanks again. :-)

Comment: Haha, no worries, it's only that I realized that I (and a lot of people too I think) have the same kind of sound going on

Comment: @Mikalichov oh lol! Sorry for that see my answer to see how to get rid of it in case you don't really use spells. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue solved with the help of comments on my question.

First, I tried to drop all my items - save, load and.. still same strange sound.

Second - done the same with my follower. No luck.

Next I tried to dismiss my follower (she did have some default stuff I couldn't take) - no cigar.

Then I just unfavorited and unequipped all my **spells** (and powers) and lo and behold - the sound was finally gone when loading!

As I have over 20 I didn't have the time (and patience) to favorite/equip them one by one until finding what exactly caused the effect so if anyone is up to the task of researching this any further I'll give my eternal gratitude. :)